# Output with parameters in Serilog does no work

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file, serilog-aspnetcore

In a .Net Core Webapi project I am using Serilog to log. But when I use `_logger.LogInformation("Token for user {UserName} created",data.username);` and check the log file, the output is `"Token for user {Username} created"`. The **{Username}** is not replaced with the real value. I am sure that the value is not null.

I use this in a LoginService and the Serilog setting in the appsetting.json is

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Information"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "C:\\Users\\ab\\Projects\\IQC\\IQC_Log.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
        "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone help to point out where I did wrong?

Comment: normally an unexpanded braced identifier is down to an entirely missing argument, i.e. that would happen if you didnt pass any arguments. Given its not sink specific, I'd say this whole question is independent of which sink(s) is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're getting JSON in that file as expected, the problem will be that you're using `CompactJsonFormatter`, which does not render message templates.

Instead, you need to pass `Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter` for the `formatter` arg.